# Ubuntu 19.10 Emergency Mode - Transfer all files to new Ubuntu partition?

Tags: partitioning, 19.10

I am kind of in a pickle right now. I have a Xiaomi Redmibook 14 running Ubuntu 19.10. It has been working perfectly for the past few months, but I did something stupid and messed up my partitions. Currently, the Laptop is running two copies of Ubuntu 19.10 (we'll say my old one that I had been using for months is old-U and then new one is new-U)

new-U is a new copy of 19.10 that works fine, but the old-u will only boot into Emergency mode. I have tried almost everything on the internet regarding emergency mode (fstab, boot-repair, etc.) but nothing seems to work. What I am wondering now is if there is a way to transfer all of my files, settings, applications from old-U to the new-U. I have full access the files from the old-U, and I have backed up my home folder.

I guess to be concise, my question is how to get new-U to look and feel exactly like old-U did with all of my files on it. I have a lot of school work on the laptop, and various pieces of software that I have already customzied to my precise needs. I would very much like to have my old system completely back on the new one.

I have been stressing for the past few days, so thank you very much in advanced for the help!

-CYG

Comment: copying /home/[userid] from the old to the new will go a long way to get you there.

Comment: How did you "mess up your partitions"? What's the exact error you see when booting the older installation? Do you have good backups? There may not be an easy way out of this, and I may end up recommending a clean Ubuntu install, after fixing the partition problem.